# How to make Google App Service publicly visible

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a Node JS app that I have running on Google Cloud Platform using the Google Shell, using git clone etc.  I can preview the endpoint, but only I can access it.  How would I make this public?

I tried "gcloud app deploy" but it seems this needs billing access, even though I'm using the trial.  Or is that correct?  I'm part of an organisation so not the user that's signed up for the trial, so would that mean getting the person who did to enable my account?

Nick.

Comment: Might I ask which GCP product are you using? Google Cloud Compute Engine?

Comment: That I'm not entirely sure tbh, it's just a node JS app that I want to run a single instance of.  I'm new to Google Cloud.

Comment: sorry, maybe "deployed" was too strong of a word.  I cloned my git repo and run the node app, then previewed it.  But no one else can see it.

Comment: I think compute engine would be the right choice after reading some descriptions.

Comment: You need to go to the network panel inside GCP, and inside the Firewall tab, allow TCP 80 and TCP 443 for the inbound ports, so then you can have access from your web browser or any other HTTP client

Comment: thanks, if you write that as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: adding an external IP might be the precondition, else `tcp:80` & `tcp:443` are rather useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many options in Google Cloud Platform to deploy your Node.js application and expose the endpoint to the public internet: App Engine, Compute Engine, Kubernetes Engine.

As I can understand you are using Cloud Shell to download the code from a Git repository and to test your application in there. Web Preview will prompt you to the Google log in page, so it is not an option if you want the endpoint be accessible to others publicly.

The command you are using (gcloud app deploy) is for App Engine. I think you are in the right direction here, since App Engine will serve as the container of your application and will let you deploy your service to the public internet without any additional configuration. At this point I would recommend you to follow the step by step guide in [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/quickstart).

About the role required to enable the App Engine API, you will need a project owner or project editor role.

Cheers.